# Magento live site keeps showing install page after deploying changes

Tags: magento, triggers, installation

I've just deployed some changes to my live site, and now it keeps bringing me to the install page. I've checked both the deploy logs and the changed files on the server, and can't work out what's triggering this.

My first thought was that I might have overwritten the main config file with the test version, but it's unchanged, and still pointing at the live database.

Compiler may have been on during the deploy - I thought I'd turned it off but the path was still set afterwards in includes/config.php
I've commented that out, but made no difference.

If I could work out what triggers the install page, I'd have a better idea of where to look.
Any suggestions?

--

Bah, I'm an idiot.

Found the problem - I had also changed the security on local.xml to 640, which was causing the problem, since my shared host needs world read access.

Once I changed that back to 644 I was then having problems where no page was working, couldn't get into admin, everything was returning a 503 error. Eventually sorted it by renaming the var/cache folder to something else - I'm guessing it might have been due to deploying while the compiler was on.

Comment: Check rhe config file permissions

Comment: Yep, thanks, that's what it was

Comment: Is there any way to resolve in windows 10?

Answer (score 3):

Something to also consider, after Mage.php checks to make sure the app/etc/local.xml file is readable, it also checks the date node. In one case I had copied a local.xml file into a new project and left that node empty which caused the site to keep triggering the install page.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error may occur when pushing files to server suppose missed to push local.xml file. First move local.xml to your live server. Then it will works..

Answer (score 0):

**Solution of Redirect install(Downloader) wizard but already installed**

> Open this file : app/Mage.php
>
> Find this below code :

```
$localConfig = simplexml_load_file($localConfigFile);
```

> Change it to the below code :

```
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
e$localConfig = simplexml_load_file($localConfigFile);
```

> Note : Clear cache or check to private window